# Pivot table hyperlinks & Text to display

Tags: vba, excel

I am using excel 2013. Need help in adding Text to display inside pivot table using Excel VBA. ?

[image: Pivot table screenshot]

So in the above pivot table the [HyperLink] should display [Invoice Num] but not the complete hyperlink address, maybe using "text to display"???

I am using VBA to create hyperlinks in pivot tables using the following code :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        On Error Resume Next
        ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink _
            Address:=CStr(Target.Value), _
            NewWindow:=True
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: That code doesn't create hyperlinks at all, so you can't use TextToDisplay. You could remove that field from the pivot altogether and use a lookup from the `Invoice Number` field to find the path to use as the address.

Comment: The challenge for is to keep the Pivot table. Cannot make any alterations here as it is the back end to a Report.

Comment: You'd have to apply a custom number format to each cell in the hyperlink field range that formats it to display the Invoice number to the left, probably using the PivotTableUpdate event.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of the code to override the format of the Hyperlink column:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).RowFields("Hyperlink").DataRange.Cells
        cell.NumberFormat = ";;;""" & cell.PivotCell.PivotRowLine.PivotLineCells.Item(cell.PivotField.Position - 1).Range.Value & """"
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: I have no idea what the relevance of that comment is?

Comment: It worked for me with a pivot table set up to resemble the picture you posted. I can't comment as to why it doesn't work for you without knowing what you actually did and what your pivot table looks like.

Comment: I don't have it any more - it was just a temporary testing file. It would be simpler for you to post a file somewhere (e.g. OneDrive or Dropbox).

Comment: The file is a simple version of the extended file that I have.

Comment: The code in the Worksheet code module needs to refer to `PivotTables(1) not `PivotTables(2)` as there's only one pivot table.